# No logcat tab in android device monitor

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I have an issue with my phone at the moment so am using an emulator within android studio.

I have launched android device monitor from android studio.

I understand android device monitor is meant to have a logcat tab, as in the tabs should be "threads, heap, **logcat**, allocations, network, file explorer..."

In instructions i've seen it here
[image]

for me, the logcat tab seems to be missing.

Why is it missing and how can I make it show?

I can do adb debug from the command line and get a long listing. And I have launched my emulator already from android studio.

Here is a screenshot from my computer - note the tabs Threads, Heap, but no logcat.

[image]

Comment: above image from your computer? If so what is bottom left tab?

Comment: well spotted EagleEye.. the instructions i'd seen had the tab in a different location. Would you like to post your comment as an answer? i'll accept it

Comment: done. I have updated it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In The above image posted in your question, in the second screenshot you give, the large screenshot from your computer, there is a Logcat window at bottom left. Circled below.

(As opposed to the top row where it was in the instructions you mentioned)

[image]